# ROracle - dbWriteTable, date columns

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

How can I write data frame with date columns to Oracle database using `dbWriteTable`? I am trying:

```
df <-read.table(header = TRUE, sep = ',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
text="
id,product,origination_date,repayment_date
1,A,2012-01-01,2012-02-01
2,A,2012-01-01,2012-04-01
3,A,2012-01-01,NA
4,A,2012-02-01,2012-03-01
")

df$origination_date <- as.Date(df$origination_date, format = '%Y-%d-%m')
df$repayment_date <- as.Date(df$repayment_date, format = '%Y-%d-%m')
names(df) <- toupper(names(df))

dbWriteTable(oraCon, 'TMP', df)
```

This is result in database:

```
1   A   31-DEC-11 11.00.00.000000 PM    01-JAN-12 11.00.00.000000 PM
2   A   31-DEC-11 11.00.00.000000 PM    03-JAN-12 11.00.00.000000 PM
3   A   31-DEC-11 11.00.00.000000 PM    
4   A   01-JAN-12 11.00.00.000000 PM    02-JAN-12 11.00.00.000000 PM
```

I can maybe understand that I end up with timestamp and not date, but cannot understand why there is `31-DEC-11` where I wanted `01-JAN-12`.

Comment: It is 1 hour difference (31.12 23:00) like GMT to CET time? Try to convert with as.POSIXct instead of as.Date.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is due to the timezone settings of both your operating system and your Oracle session. You can change these settings as follows:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='CET')
Sys.setenv(ORA_SDTZ='CET')
```

Obviously you may have to choose a different timezone. I include these settings in the beginning of all my R scripts, but there may be a way to make these settings your new default.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG256) for more information on the Oracle timezone parameters.

Comment: This is the solution.