# Can you explain this inconsistent behavior with date import?

Tags: r, oracle, date, import, roracle

You have to be able to connect to an oracle database with the package ROracle to run this example.

I cannot explain this behavior:

```
library(ROracle)

## Here you have to set up your connection with details I cannot provide
conn <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle", dbname = "xxxxxx")

query <- ("select to_date('03/28/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY') as D from dual")

rs <- dbSendQuery(conn, query)

fetch(rs)
```

And this the result I got:

```
                     D
1 2019-03-27  23:00:00
```

Ok we are almost there, just have to wait for an extra hour but what is happening here?

Comment: Looks like you're treating the date as a timestamp with time zone somewhere, and the implicit conversion is applying an hour offset for daylight savings?

Comment: @AlexPoole How to control that from the ROracle package or inside the Oracle platform where I am a simple user with no privilege?

Comment: I don't know ROracle I'm afraid, that's just what the offset suggests to me. Maybe edit the question to show how you are extracting and displaying the value after you fetch `rs`. (Which may be obvious to R users, but I have no idea *8-)

Comment: The table I show is the output of the fetch command

Comment: Possibly a timezone mismatch then; [does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44798510/266304) (using your own time zone for both values)?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes it does.